# Why did the world average CO_2 emissions per capita dip in the 1990s?

Tags: history, statistics, climate-change, industrial-policy

According to [this chart](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.ATM.CO2E.PC), per-capita CO_2 emissions in the world peaked in the late 1980s, then dipped quickly, and did not reach their 1989 level again until 2011.

What are the major factors explaining this dip?

Comment: The data source switched in 1990, per the note at the top of the graph: "Data for up to 1990 are sourced from Carbon Dioxide Information Analysis Center, Environmental Sciences Division, Oak Ridge National Laboratory, Tennessee, United States. Data from 1990 are CAIT data." As such, the answer to this question likely involves an understanding of the data sources, and is probably a better fit for EarthScience.SE

Comment: This isn't really a political question.  It is an [Earthscience.se] question with an answer that may have political implications.

Comment: @JamesK: On the contrary, it is very much a political question. Natural circumstances did not cause this to happen. I suppose you might be able to argue it belongs on history.SE, but it's close enough to present affairs to merit being here, I think.

Comment: Seeing how critically urgent and how politically sensitive managing emissions is turning out to be, it seems to me that keeping track of circumstances when CO2 went down is of immediate interest to public policy.

Comment: An alternate source which does not show this same anomaly: [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/co-emissions-per-capita?tab=chart&time=1960..2020&country=~OWID_WRL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from any glitches in the data or methodology changes, in the 90s, the world did experience a significant dip in [absolute CO2 emissions](https://ourworldindata.org/co2-emissions), for a short while.

[image]

This was due to the collapse of the USSR and the Eastern bloc states.  They had, up until that point, developed using hugely inefficient and outdated heavy industry, with very little care for the environment and efficiency.

Once the Soviet Union went away and planned economy stopped, whole swaths of their industry found themselves without anybody wanting to buy their goods and demand collapsed (for example, the much regretted [Trabant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trabant)).  Since these factories were inefficient energetically, their [shutdown](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2009/dec/09/eugene-robinson/robinson-claims-fall-ussr-meant-big-drop-greenhous/) was especially significant in terms of limiting CO2.  Add to it that there were also consumer-level recessions affecting much of Russia, thus [reducing emissions even more, at least partially due to reduced meat consumption](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-02024-6) and [agricultural lands becoming fallow](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2009/dec/09/eugene-robinson/robinson-claims-fall-ussr-meant-big-drop-greenhous/).

[Russia set to approve climate change plan](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn6467-russia-set-to-approve-climate-change-plan/) (2004)

> For example, the EU has to reduce emissions by 8%, while Russia has only to keep them from rising above 1990 levels.
>
> That should not be hard. **Its emissions are currently more than 25% below 1990 levels, following the collapse of the Soviet economy in the early 1990s.**

The USSR's demise impact on CO2 was very much in the news in the late 90s, early 2000s.

In impact and duration, this seems roughly comparable to what happened during other oil shocks and recessions like 1974 and 2008.

Comment: also the world population grew quickly in the 90s, lowering per-capita amounts even in a constant or slightly increasing output.